# Report viewer not working in Windows 8

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have been developing an APP.Net web app on a Windows 7 64bit machine, using Visual Studio 2012. I deploy it to a host, and all is good. Report shows as expected.

I just got a new development laptop, but it has Windows 8 64bit. I installed the same version of visual studio 2012, and applied all patches.

But now when I get the solution loaded, and either publish, or run locally, when I load the report screen - nothing happens. No error... just a blank screen. I am using the same code.

Even if I load the published site from the old win7 machine, no report.

I then recompile, and republish from the Win7 - and all is working. For some reason, the report isn't being compiled, or handled properly on the Win8 machine. Has anyone seen this, or have any ideas?

Comment: ReportViewer might not work well with IE10, have you tried other browsers or compatibility mode?

Comment: I was hoping that, but it's happening with Chrome. And when I publish from my Win7 machine - it runs on my Win8 PC. It's only when I compile and publish from the Win8 machine, it fails on all browsers.

Comment: Resolved: The problem was that I had a version of Ajax that seems incompatible with .Net 4.5. I found a version on the Win7 machine, copied it on, and it all works. Strange, as the version I downloaded says for 4.5. But was different to the version on my old PC...